# How to design one to one relationship in EF Core that points only in one direction

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I'm trying to design very simple database model with EF Core 3 but I'm having issues with very simple relationship.

I have classes: Customer, Document and Address.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Street { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

So I want to use generic Address in different entities.

I'm trying to model it like in a following way:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(f => f.Id);
    builder.HasOne(f => f.Address).WitMany().IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Document> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(f => f.Id);
    builder.HasOne(f => f.Address).WitMany().IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Address> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(f => f.Id);
    builder.Property(f => f.Street);
    builder.Property(f => f.City);
}
```

But the problem is that when I have my document with an address attached to it and I try to remove that document, the address won't be removed. For some reason Address is a principal over document.

How to model such relationship? I can't have navigation property in Address entity as Address can be used in multiple different entities as a generic representation of an address.

Comment: Remove `DeleteBehavior.Cascade`  from the entities. That's not going to work with shared entities. What you need to is is  `onDelete: ReferentialAction.SetNull` and set all references to the document to null before deleting it.

Comment: But will it solve the problem with not deleting Address after I delete Document? When I call dbContext.Remove(document) i want it to remove automatically the document.Address entity attached to it.

Comment: You can't delete it because `Address` is attached to a `Customer`. Don't use cascade delete in this instance. Step 1. Set every reference  of `Address` to null. Step 2. Delete `Address`. Step 3. Delete `Document`.

Comment: It seems in the non-core version of EF it was possible: https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations

modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOptional(u => u.BillingAddress)
                               .WithRequired()
                               .WillCascadeOnDelete();

Comment: It's not possible in relational database, hence is not possible in EF (Core or not). `Address` can be configured to be dependent side of one-to-one *only* with single principal entity. But you want to use it in more than one entity, so the PK cannot be used as FK. The only way is to create 2 (or N) mutually exclusive FKs.

Comment: Another option is to make `Address` an [owned type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities), but that significantly changes the database model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Ivan for pointing out that it's not possible. I will follow Gerd's advice to use owned type.